# Visual Studio professional Edition 2017 Linker

Tags: c++, c++17, linker-errors, visual-c++-2017

I recently converted my project from C++11 to C++17, under visual-Studio 2017 and immediately started experiencing problems with the Linker as follows:

> LINK : the 32-bit linker
> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe) failed to do memory mapped file I/O on `C:\Git\Raptor\temp\MsBuild\Output\Debug_v141\Rev2Aux_Debug.lib' and is going to restart linking with a 64-bit linker for better throughput
> 7>LINK : failed to locate a 64-bit linker on %PATH%, continuing the current linking; please consider switching to 64-bit linker

Essentially, what it is, the builder tries to employ the use of a 64-bit Linker for larger Libs but cannot find it in the `%PATH%` so it resorts back to the 32-bit Linker, and does this for every occasion that it encounters this issue, which is often. This significantly slows down build times for me.

Now, everything about my VisualStudio environment and my Windows version are 64-Bit, so I don't know what else to do.

What could be the solution?

The other issue I have noticed since this conversion to C++17 is how much slower the response of the VisualStudio editor and debugger are. For example, changing between windows during debugging sessions takes ages.

Comment: There's not really any need to add statements like "Many thanks" to the post. It's considered to be unnecessary, and we assume that you are thankful for any help you receive :)

Comment: It's considered polite and civilised in the world of intelligent Homosapients to express gratitude toward one's fellow man.
Clearly, it is something that the less evolved hominids in our midst find objectionable.

Many Thanks BTW, Rez

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been clearer about why I edited your question. Yes, you're absolutely right, expressing gratitude *is* the polite, and civilized thing to do. However, SO is intended to be used as a question/answer site, and while no one objects to "thank you" comments per se, it's seen as distracting when one is only trying to find the answer to some question. Here's a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) about this very issue.

Comment: We're not trying to be impolite when we remove such comments, we're just trying to keep the site clean :) Please feel free to ask for clarifications on this concept.